# Verschwenden und Verschwinden

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, standard-german

Haben diese beiden Verben die gleiche Bedeutung? Oder gibt es vielleicht einen feinen Unterschied? Kann jemand mir bitte erklären?

Comment: Falls Dir ein gutes Wörterbuch keine Klarheit bringt, wäre es gut, wenn Du Deine Frage editierst und ergänzt, was genau unklar oder widersprüchlich ist. Dann können wir darauf gezielt eingehen. (fyi: Nach dem Edit kann eine geschlossene Frage auch wieder geöffnet werden, wenn sie dann on-topic ist)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bei solchen Fragen hat man es leichter, wenn man sich alternativ zur Bedeutung auch Synonyme der Worte ansieht:

> - Synonym fürs "Verschwenden": unnötig verbrauchen
> - Synonym fürs "Verschwinden": abhauen/weg- oder verloren gehen

Demnach kannst du dir schon denken, dass beide Verben nicht dieselbe Bedeutung haben.